# Mudar value do input de acordo com o value de um option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu estou tentando desenvolver uma funcionalidade diferenciada para fins de estudo e até o momento nao consegui desenvolver.

#### O que preciso fazer:

Eu vou ter um campo `input` do tipo `hidden` e precisava que ele ganhasse o mesmo valor que fosse atribuído (como `selected`) no `option` de um `select`. Segue o código:

```
<form id="formulario">
<!--
Aqui deixei o value vazio para fins de entender o que da pra fazer com ele.
 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="categoriaId" value="">

    <select class="categorias_select" name="categoria_id" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="14"> CATEGORIA 01 </option>
        <option value="15"> CATEGORIA 02 </option>
        <option value="16" selected="selected"> CATEGORIA 03 </option>
        <option value="17"> CATEGORIA 04 </option>
        <option value="18"> CATEGORIA 05 </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Então, quando eu selecionar a **Categoria 01** o value do `input` muda para **14**.

Eu consegui fazer isso apenas com `PHP` mas quero entender de fazer esse processo através do `javascript/jQuery`

Espero que de para entender a ideia e estarei aqui para mais informações.

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. 
Grato!

Comment: Lougans, acho que a segunda pergunta da lista deve resolver. QQ coisa avisa aí.

Comment: @Sam Mano, vlw.. a pergunta da segunda lista me ajudou sim. Nossa, achei que teria que fazer muitas associações haha.. Vlw mano.